# Cocos2d Custom Scene Transition -- Book Cover Opening

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, transition

I am trying to create a custom scene transition in Cocos2D for iOS that will simulate the opening of a book cover.

The out-going scene must flip open to the left (hinged on the left edge of the screen) and display the in-coming scene as if it where the first page of the book just being uncovered by the out-going scene.

Any ideas on how to do this?

I was able to create a subclass of `CCTransitionSceneOriented` the performs a simple, book cover transition, unfortunately is not professional looking because the in-coming scene is not incrementally displayed as the cover is opened :-(

```
@implementation TransitionBookCover

-(void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    [inScene_ setVisible:NO];

    id  outCameraAct = [CCOrbitCamera actionWithDuration:duration_/2 radius:1 deltaRadius:0 angleZ:180 deltaAngleZ:65 angleX:0 deltaAngleX:0];
    id outHideAct   = [CCHide action];
    id outDelayAct  = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:duration_/2];
    id outGroupAct1 = [CCSequence actions:outCameraAct, outHideAct, outDelayAct, nil];
    id outMoveAct   = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration_/4 position:ccp(-384.0,0.0)];
    id outGroupAct2 = [CCSpawn actions:outMoveAct, outGroupAct1, nil];

    id inDelayAct = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:duration_/2];
    id inShowAct  = [CCShow action];
    id inFuncAct  = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finish)];
    id inGroupAct = [CCSequence actions:inDelayAct, inShowAct, inFuncAct, nil];

    [outScene_ runAction:outGroupAct2];
    [inScene_ runAction:inGroupAct];    
}

@end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have to do this with scenes.  You can do it cheaply 2 ways:

1. pre-render the book cover opening and run it as an animation
2. make the cover a sprite on the "first page" and then just shrink the x coordinate until it disappears.  I'm not sure how to get a "trapezoidal" effect in Cocos2D.

`CCTransitionFlipX` is more for flipping a card over, than the 1st page of a book.

Comment: I think I will go with the pre-render solution, because my attempt with Cocos2d does not have enough quality.

Comment: @Jay, Without high quality 3D stuff it's hard.

Comment: Maybe I can use the tried and true solution -- tweak the interface to do something else cool (something that is easier to do with quality).  :-)

Comment: @Jay Haase, this continues to be a popular question on SO.  I saw this answer fly by recently:  http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks Stephen, you have been a big help to me, and I really appreciate it, because I know it takes time to help others.